# argument out of range exception in a memory puzzle game

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm following along a course on udemy which is for free it's a memory game (https://www.udemy.com/xamarin-native-ios-memory-game-csharp/learn/v4/overview)

Now with the randomizer method i get a new problem with the same out of range error

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UIKit;

namespace iOSMemoryGame
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        #region vars

    List<String> imgArr = new List<String>();

    float gameViewWidth;
    int gridSize = 6;

    ArrayList tilesArr = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList coordsArr = new ArrayList();

    #endregion

    public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

        // make sure Game View is Laid Out
        gameView.LayoutIfNeeded();
        gameViewWidth = (float)gameView.Frame.Size.Width;

        // let's load all of our images into an array
        for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++)
        {
            imgArr.Add("img_" + i.ToString() + ".png");
        }

        // let's make a call to tileMaker
        tileMaker();

        // let's call the randomizer
        randomizer();
    }

    private void randomizer()
    {
        // we are gonna go through our tiles in ORDER
        // and we are gonna assign a new center to them RANDOMLY

        foreach (UIView any in tilesArr)
        {
            // UIImageView thisTile = (UIImageView)tilesArr[i];

            Random myRand = new Random();
            int randomIndex = myRand.Next(0, coordsArr.Count);

            CoreGraphics.CGPoint newRandCenter = (CoreGraphics.CGPoint)coordsArr[randomIndex];
            any.Center = newRandCenter;

            coordsArr.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
        }
    }

    private void tileMaker()
    {
        float tileWidth = gameViewWidth / gridSize;

        float xCenter = tileWidth / 2;
        float yCenter = tileWidth / 2;

        int imgCounter = 0;

        for (int h = 0; h < gridSize; h++)
        {
            for (int v = 0; v < gridSize; v++)
            {
                UIImageView tileImgView = new UIImageView();

                CoreGraphics.CGPoint newCenter = new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(xCenter, yCenter);

                tileImgView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, tileWidth - 5, tileWidth - 5);

                String imgName = imgArr[imgCounter];
                tileImgView.Image = new UIImage(imgName);
                tileImgView.Center = newCenter;

                // user CAN interact with this image view
                tileImgView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

                // adding the new image view to the array
                tilesArr.Add(tileImgView);

                gameView.AddSubview(tileImgView);

                xCenter = xCenter + tileWidth;
                imgCounter++;

                if (imgCounter == gridSize * gridSize / 2)
                {
                    imgCounter = 0;
                }
            }

            xCenter = tileWidth / 2;
            yCenter = yCenter + tileWidth;
        }
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    partial void Rst4Button_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    partial void Rst6Button_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Something is wrong with the randomizer method but i dont know what.

it gives me again a out of range error.

without the randomizer method it works fine

[image: Error]

Comment: Try to print the value of imgCounter and the length of imgArr at that line, this might give you an idea of what is going on. My guess is that you are trying to access for example element 6 at an array that only has 6 elements. (element 6 would be the 7th element since element 1 is zero.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
for (int i = 1; i < 18; i++)
```

creates 17 images, not 18 as expected by the following loops.

```
// 0-5 = 6 loops
for (int h = 0; h < gridSize; h++)
{
    // 0-5 = 6 loops (h*v=18)
    for (int v = 0; v < gridSize; v++)
    {
        ....
```

You need to write

```
for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
   imgArr.Add("img_" + (i+1).ToString() + ".png");
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception:

System.Exception: Could not initialize an instance of the type 'UIKit.UIImage': the native 'initWithContentsOfFile:' method returned nil.
It is possible to ignore this condition by setting MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false. occurred

Comment: String imgName = imgArr[imgCounter];     The error was on this line

Comment: but after doing this: for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
   imgArr.Add("img_" + (i+1).ToString() + ".png");            it worked